# JavaScript: How To `.bind()` `Function` to Another Object

Tags: javascript, scope, this, v8

### The Facts

`Function('return this')()` always returns the global (window) object. `Function.bind({})('return this')()` returns the global object too.

### My Goals

I want to create a variation of `Function`. The anonymous functions returned by calling that variation of `Function` should always use `myObj` as `this`.

If JavaScript wouldn't behave in that special way (see *The Facts*), I would do the following:

```
var myFun = Function.bind(myObj);
```

`myFun` is the object that I want to own. Now I would be able to do the following:

```
console.assert(myObj === myFun('return this')());
```

### My Questions

- Why is `Function` returning `global`, even after `.bind()`ing it to another object?
- Is there a workaround? How can I bind `Function` to another object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially doing this:

```
Function.call({}, 'return this;')();
```

The `Function` function is executed in the context of a new anonymous object.  Doing this *does not affect* the context of the functions generated by `Function`.  It turns out that `Function` doesn't care what context it runs in -- it always produces functions that have the default global context.

If you want to specify the context of the functions generated by `Function`, you want to wrap `Function` like this:

```
// give our vars privacy in a closure
(function() {
    // store old Function
    var oldFunc = Function;

    // redefine Function to be a wrapper around the real Function
    // which takes an additional `context` argument
    Function = function(ftext, context) {
        return oldFunc(ftext).bind(context);
    }
}());
```

Now you can call `Function('return this', myObj)();` and it will return `myObj`.

---

Or, to simply create your suggested `myFun(text)` syntax which passes your `assert` test:

```
var myFun = function(ftext) {
    return Function(ftext).bind(myObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but it seems that your method chaining is in the wrong order.

```
Function('return this').bind({})() // returns the empty Object
```

Comment: Thanks, that's I nice in this use case. - But I want to create a **variation of `Function` *itself***, not a variation of a function *created by* `Function`. I want something like `var myFun = Function.bind(myObj)` as a result in a variable. If I was using your solution, I can't do something like that - Then **I'd need to `.bind()` *every* produced by `Function` *apart***.

Comment: Hm, either I am not aware enough of JavaScript or I don't understand the basic principle behind your idea. But it sounds to me that you want to overload the prototype of `.bind`. Sorry if I wasn't any of help.

Comment: I extended my question in order to make clear what I mean. I hope it's OK now.

Comment: "`it sounds to me that you want to overload the prototype of .bind`": That's not really what I keep in mind. - I don't want to do anything *with* `.bind()`, `bind()` is just my tool to create a second version of `Function`. I want that **second version *of `Function`*** (`var myFun = Function.bind(myObj);`) to return special anonymous functions (`var myRetValue = myFun('return this')`) when getting called. The special thing concerning these anonymous functions should be: **In the scope of these returned functions, `this` should refer to `myObj`** (`console.assert(myObj === myRetValue());`).

Comment: So it's all about **changing the context** of the anonymous functions returned by a `Function()` call. - Is it clear what I want to express? I hope so. If it's not: Please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, very good edit for clarification, definitely +1 from me! I think apsillers answered your question then :). Maybe one hint: Changing a context always goes along with `.call` or `.apply`.